# Offline version of tutorial

Tags: ros, tutorial, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would it be possible to have an offline version of the tutorial? The website is really slow thesedays.
A local version of http://wiki.ros.org/
or at least of http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249172/offline-version-of-tutorial/) by [Wyatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/28675/wyatt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried any of the [mirrors](http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wyatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/28675/wyatt/) on 2016-12-01**:
Thanks it is ok now with a mirror.